# Remove orange counter when I can't review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

Just a minor feature request - when I've already exhausted my reviews for the day, I'd prefer the orange "~x suggested edits pending approval" -thing to not appear until I can review again. This way I would know when I actually can make new reviews, instead of occasionally clicking the orange blip by accident only to get a "thanks but come back in y hours" message.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, that's a WHOLE different question/request.

Comment: The *answer* is exactly the same: Nope, too expensive to do this.

Comment: Personally I just ignore it. It's not that hard...

Comment: See also: [Don't show pending suggested edits to me after I run out of votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes) and all of its related posts

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Still a different feature request.

Comment: @OGHaza thanks, I tried searching for that but I guess the lack of an established name for that orange thingamajig made it harder than necessary.

Comment: @Sam, as a software developer it doesn't suit my taste to just ignore poor UX, even in minor cases like this.

Comment: Well, as a software developer you ought to have some idea how hard it is to generate 140 personalized page views *per second* on average.  One extra dbase query that takes but a few milliseconds and the site is dead.

Comment: The orange blip needs a DB query anyway, doesn't it? It only gets displayed for users with over 2,000 rep.

Comment: @kviiri It doesn't even need a DB query. Just update a field like `ReviewAllowDate` to `DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(12)` when reaching the 20 reviews limit. Or you can just _cookie_ it...

Comment: So, would it be possible to just disable that orange counter completely with a preference option? I regularly see a count of ~100, but in 9/10 times I click on it, there are no items to review for my filtered tags, so I basically try to not pay attention to it. Unfortunately, it's a really conspicuous, distracting, orange blob, so it's hard to ignore. :-(