# Do not show review alert when user reached review limit

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes at the top of the page appears red box with a number (for example 30). When I hover into it then I see that there are 30 suggested edits pending approval. The idea of this box is clear to me. This box is shouting to me:

> We are in danger. 30 enemies are attacking us. Abandon anything you are doing. Take your bow and arrows. Hug your sons, kiss your wife and stand for battle.

So I leave question half-answered, beer half-emptied and I struggle with these reviews until I see that there are no enemies left and I can return to my previous activities.

But some time later there is another summons and I have to struggle again. But there comes a moment when I shoot last arrow from my quiver. Then I receive a message:

> Thank you our brother. We will need you again tomorrow. But now you can leave the battlefield and take some sleep.

So I return home and fall asleep. But one hour later there is another call. So I jump from my bed and reach for quiver but it is still empty. So why do you call me if I cannot support you at this moment?

---

**Feature request**: Show red alert box only to users who havn't reached daily limit of suggested edits reviews.

Comment: Ahh, I just loved the analogy...

Comment: No worries, you'll get comfortable with that notification always showing the moment you can close questions...

Comment: This is very unlikely to be implemented. Most things related to reviewing (with the exception of actual reviews) are heavily cached for performance and are not be personalized for each user. There have been many discussions along these lines previously, for example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266000/review-page-does-not-work-as-before

Comment: @AndrewMedico: "user reached review limit" is very easily cached in client-side storage, and it even has a known expiration date.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262967/remove-orange-counter-when-i-cant-review and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes